# Input Data from Individual Sheet (based off cell value/name)

Tags: google-sheets

I'm wondering if it's possible to input data from a certain sheet, based the cell value of the main sheet.  So what I have, is a main sheet that I use as the "Data Board".  In the Data Board, is a column that has/will have "Load Numbers" entered.  Each of those load numbers, I want to be linked to a specific sheet (not worksheet, just page/tab/sheet).  Now, the specific sheet will not be named the same as the Load Number, but will have the load number as a cell value in the specific sheet.  If the Data Board and the Load Sheet has matching Load Numbers, can I have it to where instead of a range, it pulls only certain cell values to the Data Page?

So if on Data Board, B2 = "03/30-W1", that cell would input the data from whatever sheet has the Load Number "03/30-W1" in cell "E12".  Inputted data would be cells "A2, A4, A6, A10, B10, C10, E2, E4, E6, N18:N20" from each sheet it (Data Board) found matching Load Numbers in.

The Load Numbers/Load Sheets change daily, so I'd like a way for this to be automated instead of having manually link the Data Board to the Load Sheet.

The other option, is if it's possible to have a checkbox on the Data Board, where once it's checked (true), it creates a sheet based on a separate template (Master Quote Sheet).  The Data Board would then know to pull data from the corresponding load sheet.

If this is possible, I'd REALLY appreciate any input!  Thank you in advance!  Here's a link to a what I'm working on.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1J1w2JEopWQzu-Li1DGxlfqfNBwE7DpWox8s6wjnonrI/edit?usp=sharing

***Update***  Here's a response I got on Reddit that actually seems to work pretty well, and was a new idea to me.  Here's the Reddit link as well (https://www.reddit.com/r/sheets/comments/fw9ard/input_data_from_individual_sheet_based_off_cell/)

"The easiest way would be to have the Load ID on each sheet, then use

=QUERY({'Data Board'!A2:U},"select Col4 where Col2 = '"&$E$12&"' limit 1")
Change Col4 (which is Data Board'!D:D) to match the column you want to return.

I included limit 1 in the formula so it only returns the first row that matches the Load ID -- you may not need this. We can also filter down by the status.

=QUERY(
 {'Data Board'!A2:U},
 "select Col4 
   where 
    Col2 = '"&$E$12&"' and
    Col3 = 'Booked'
   limit 1")
Col1 = A, Col2 = B etc. I filled this in on QUERY - TX to GA"

I did respond to that comment, if you're interested in what I was thinking about next to be able to utilize this as an option.

Comment: Are you planning on using the Data Board for all editing of data or did you want to use the individual sheets to store the data? You can't use both at the same time without there being a conflict of editing both at the same time. I was going to post an answer but it seems what you want is not very clear... for example you wanted the Data Board linked to your Load Sheets but then you say you want a checkbox to actually create a new Load Sheet which is contradictory since the Data Board is grabbing the information from the Load Sheet not the other way around unless you want it that way.

Comment: 90% of the data going to be entered will be on the Load Sheets. Load Sheets will be duplicates of the "Master Quote Sheet", with updated information based on what load/project is being worked. I'd love to be able to just have a check box on the Data Board that will generate a load sheet based off the quote sheet template, but I understand that may be a bit more difficult.  Once the load sheet is generated, it would automatically populate the low/median/high numbers over to the data board.

Comment: If your edit is the answer to your question you should remove it from the question and actually post an answer yourself in a way where it can be helpful to someone reading.

Comment: I wouldn't say that it's an actual answer yet, as it kind of does what I need it to, but also doesn't... :-/

Comment: Then you should make your question more specific to the specific portion that does not do what you want because it sounds like you asked a question and then answered it.